# best way to make a universal variable

Tags: ios, global

I am creating an app that use the same set of buttons in different views I have them in wht blue gry and yellow and I would like to be able to change them all across all views by setting a single variable called prfix "someplace" so that all view could reference that single reference and use the correct colors

I would use this to set the buttons on each page but would like to change the color in a single location

I have this for each button on each page where they are used

```
    [Button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-butt1.png",prfix]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

my images in the bundle would be something like

ylw-butt1.png, ylw-butt2.png, ylw-butt3.png, ylw-butt4.png, blu-butt1.png, blu-butt2.png, blu-butt3.png, blu-butt4.png

so by changing prfix in the one location to ylw or blu I could swap all button colors

Comment: "so by changing prfix in the one location to ylw or blu" - did the "e" key fall off your keyboard?

Comment: no I was making them all short and not normal since I wanted to be able use things like prefix or yellow or blue for other things. They would be static in nature so the actual spelling was not critical I also use gry and wht

Comment: OK. :) Anyway, you might want to read this discussion of mine on where to put globally available info: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_global_visibility

Comment: Submit your last comment as an answer and I will choose it. I actually was thinking about the NSDEFAULTS but was wondering if there was a better way you link gave good options and reasonings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Various "locations" in your app are globally visible, such as the app delegate, the root view controller, and the NSUserDefaults storage. These are all reasonable places to use as a "drop" to place a value that any object can retrieve. (And see my discussion of the matter here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_global_visibility)